# Switch ignore case in java 7

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-7

I am doing a POC on Java 7 new features. I have code to use String in switch statement and it works. I want to make it work in case insensitive also. Is there a way to check out with ignoreCase on String?

```
package com.java.j7;

public class Test {
    final private String _NEW ="NEW";
    final private String _PENDING = "PENDING";
    final private String _CLOSED = "CLOSED";
    final private String _REJECTED ="REJECTED";

public static void main(String... strings){

    Test j = new Test();
    j.processItem("new");
    j.processItem("pending");
    j.processItem("closed");
    j.processItem("rejected");

}

void processItem(String s){
    switch (s) {
    case _NEW:
        System.out.println("Matched to new");
        break;
    case _PENDING:
        System.out.println("Matched to pending");
        break;
    case _CLOSED:
        System.out.println("Matched to closed");
        break;
    case _REJECTED:
        System.out.println("Matched to rejected");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Not matching any more");
        break;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

no, but you could switch on `s.toUpperCase()`. so:

```
switch (s.toUpperCase()) {
   //same as before
}
```

and while we're nitpicking, you better upper-case things in the english locale to [avoid issues with turkish](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug)

Comment: In this case I would suggest `s.toUpperCase` as the matches are in upper case ;)

Comment: i originally included code that lowercased the constants as well, but yeah, uppercase is less work

Comment: Today, I would prefer `Locale.ROOT` in these case to document the fact that these hard-coded constants are not really English culture issues. It was added in Java 6. By the way, today there are more locales than Turkish with special case matching behavior.

Answer (score 9):

using String in switch Example from oracle docs [Using Strings in switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
 public class StringSwitchDemo {

        public static int getMonthNumber(String month) {

            int monthNumber = 0;

            if (month == null) {
                return monthNumber;
            }

            switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
                case "january":
                    monthNumber = 1;
                    break;
                case "february":
                    monthNumber = 2;
                    break;
                case "march":
                    monthNumber = 3;
                    break;
                case "april":
                    monthNumber = 4;
                    break;
                case "may":
                    monthNumber = 5;
                    break;
                case "june":
                    monthNumber = 6;
                    break;
                case "july":
                    monthNumber = 7;
                    break;
                case "august":
                    monthNumber = 8;
                    break;
                case "september":
                    monthNumber = 9;
                    break;
                case "october":
                    monthNumber = 10;
                    break;
                case "november":
                    monthNumber = 11;
                    break;
                case "december":
                    monthNumber = 12;
                    break;
                default: 
                    monthNumber = 0;
                    break;
            }

            return monthNumber;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String month = "August";

            int returnedMonthNumber =
                StringSwitchDemo.getMonthNumber(month);

            if (returnedMonthNumber == 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid month");
            } else {
                System.out.println(returnedMonthNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From oracle docs [switch with string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> The String in the switch expression is compared with the expressions associated with each case label as if the [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method were being used.

You can use

```
switch(s.toUpperCase()){
...
.....
}
```

See also

- [String#toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29)